# Symfony Doctrine relations nor partials works on DQL

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship, dql

First of all, here is what I have:

**DeviceContentUpdate** entity:

```
Bundle\Entity\DeviceContentUpdate:
  type: entity
  table: device_content_updates
  repositoryClass: ...
  id:
      id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
  fields:
      ...
      deviceId:
        type: integer
        column: device_id
        nullable: true
  manyToOne:
      relDevice:
        targetEntity: Device
        inversedBy: relDeviceContentUpdates
        joinColumn:
            name: device_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

**Device** entity:

```
Bundle\Entity\Device:
  type: entity
  table: devices
  repositoryClass: ...
  id:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
  fields: [...]
  oneToMany:
    relDeviceContentUpdates:
        targetEntity: DeviceContentUpdate
        mappedBy: relDevice
```

Now when I try to fetch one item by id using QueryBuilder it fails to construct proper JOIN caluse, meaning it joins all the records in case of many-to-one relation.

**Example 1**:

```
 $result = $deviceContentUpdateRepository
   ->createQueryBuilder('mt')
   ->select('mt')
   ->leftJoin('Bundle:Device', 'd')
   ->where('mt.id = ?0')
   ->setParameter(0, $id)
   ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

**Result 1**: List of DeviceContentUpdate items with as much items as there are in Device entity's table.

**Expected result 1**: List with one DeviceContentUpdate item including related Device item accessible by relDevice() method. I know I can fetch object without join clause and use lazy loader, this is only to illustrate the situation.

**Example 2**:

```
$result = $deviceContentUpdateRepository
   ->createQueryBuilder('mt')
   ->select('mt')
   ->leftJoin('Bundle:Device', 'd', 'WITH', 'd.id = mt.deviceId')
   ->where('mt.id = ?0')
   ->setParameter(0, $id)
   ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

**Result 2**: Expected result from **Example 1**

**Example 3**:

```
$result = $deviceContentUpdateRepository
   ->createQueryBuilder('mt')
   ->select('mt, partial d.{id,name}')
   ->leftJoin('Bundle:Device', 'd', 'WITH', 'd.id = mt.deviceId')
   ->where('mt.id = ?0')
   ->setParameter(0, $id)
   ->getQuery()->getResult(); // mode HYDRATE_OBJECT
```

**Result 3**: List of two items, 0 item is DeviceContentUpdate, 1 item is proxy of Device.

**Expected result 3**: List of one DeviceContentUpdate item.

I'm really confused, cause all the manuals and examples says that there is no reason to use WITH in JOIN clauses if only FK's are mapped, but in my case it joins everything if I don't use it. Also I'm getting all my hairs out from head with partials. Literally have no idea of this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You should try this, this example works.

```
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
  ->from('Embed', 'e')
  ->select("e")
  ->leftJoin("User", "u", "WITH", "e.uid=u.id")
  ->leftJoin("Product", "p", "WITH", "e.pid=p.id")
  ->where("u.image > 0 OR p.image > 0")
  ->addOrderBy("COALESCE( u.timeCreated, p.timeCreated )", "DESC")
  ->setMaxResults(28)
  ->getQuery();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing related to the topic. -1 :/